# Passing instance variables to instance methods vs. directly accessing them?

Tags: java, instance-variables

Imagine I have a class with an instance member

```
String instanceMember;
```

Further I have like 4 instance methods accessing this member. Now I am wondering if there is any real pro/con for either directly accessing the instance member from the instance methods or to pass the instance member as a parameter to each of the instance methods?

Comment: Basically, what "feels right".  Sometimes it's a good idea to pass the reference, just as a sort of "documentation" that you're operating on it.  (But never be afraid to go back and change a parm passing scheme if it starts seeming wrong -- many atrocities are committed in the name of avoiding (trivial) change.)

Answer (score 6):

Passing the value as a parameter would imply that you are going to perform the calculation with the parameter value rather than the encapsulated value.

If you are going to operate on encapsulated data then there is no reason to have it as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for having *instance* variables in the first place is to avoid passing them as parameters: your *instance* method gets to access them "for free", because they are already in the method's scope.

There are two reasons to pass instance variables to methods, though:

- **The method is `static`** - class methods cannot access instance variables, so you need to pass them explicitly, or pass the object on which to operate
- **You need to use pass-by-value semantic** - in other words, you would like to modify the value passed in, and you would like to avoid creating a local variable. This is often the case when the method is *recursive*.

If you find yourself writing recursive code that modifies a parameter which started off as an instance variable, in many cases it may be a good idea to make your method `private static`, and add a `public` instance method to start the recursive chain and to harvest the results.

Comment: In that second case you're not technically passing the instance variable.

Comment: @HotLicks Good point, thanks! I added a discussion at the bottom to elaborate on what to do in the second case.

Comment: I think that the "pass-by-value semantic" thing gets confused when you're talking about objects.  By passing an object reference into the method, vs letting the method reference the instance var, you do not change the fact that modifying the object will have a global effect.  This area is one where newbies get seriously confused at times.

Answer (score 0):

If these methods are public methods that manipulate the state of a persistent member variable, you shouldn't really be passing it around. For example, if you have to do something like the following, it should probably be manipulated directly by the method instead of being passed in:

```
myObject.SomeMethod(myObject.instanceMember, 15);
```

This should really just be:

```
myObject.SomeMethod(15);
```

If it's something that might change per call (such as, for example, the mysterious `15` in the method above), you'll want to pass it around.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend a lot on how you use it. If the usage of you class is infrequent, then there will be no obvious difference.

If you are using the class instance a lot, and by many threads, then in some conditions, passing it as a parameter would work a bit faster.

Usually instance members are accessed directly by class members with exeptions of static functions (due to obvious reasons).

So follow your coding conventions and don't worry. By the time it would really matter you will know the answer by heart.